# Cant exploit overflow in simple program (chapter2 shellcoder's handbook)

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am reading The shellcoder's Handbook and im currently at chapter 2 where i have a simple program to exploit by overflowing the expected input and then issuing a new location for the ret instruction so that the function return_input can be executed twice !

Here is the simple program made in C

```
void return_input (void)
{
  char array[30];
  gets (array);
  printf(“%s\n”, array);
}
main()
{
  return_input();
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the disassembled version of the main fucntion where we can see the jump adress of the call function.

[image: Dissas]

I use the following command and input the chars that overflow with the adress following them that should replace ret's content

[image: printf]

But as you can see i do not run the return_input function twice  instead it just prints out a question mark and says segmentation failed

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: These kind of "exploits" are always so stupid... what would you do if the return address happens to contain a byte with value 0x00? Which in turn seems pretty damn likely, even without ASLR.

Comment: Please do not paste text as image. No one wants a screenshot of your whole screen to see 2 lines of text!

Comment: Have you tried debugging the program with the expected input?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau I tried but gdb wont let me instert breakpoints it says cannot access memory

Comment: If you're trying to insert a breakpoint and gdb says "can't access memory at address X", is because X is not an address in your program. You need to pass it the correct memory address.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau i tried multiple adresses and i tried the one in the book too

Comment: You need the address of the function when the program executes to set a breakpoint. The book can't possibly know this before hand. If you want to learn how to exploit code, I suggest you first try to learn everything about gdb, as it will be an invaluable tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `gets` read terminating byte in and replaced it with NULL byte and thus your desired `ret` was broken with that NULL byte.
2. The offset you saw in disassembly codes is *NOT* the real address, you compiled the program with `PIE` flag set so the real address may look like `0x55555????58a`, that's why gdb didn't allow you to insert a break point because you might try to do `b *0x58a` or something. Compile with   `-no-pie` would make life easier.